# Laravel 5.2 - default error page for undefined routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Suppose I have this in my routes.php :

```
Route::get('sells', ['as' => 'user_sells', 'uses' => 'SellsController@indexAll']);
```

Now, as you know, if someone opens mySite.com/sells, the desired method in the controller would be executed.

But, if someone tried to access to a route which is not defined at all, like mySite.com/buys , I want to show a default error page. I mean, I need to say if a route is not defined, show a specific page.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

**Added:**
The error I face to when I try to access an undefined route:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> ErrorException in
> C:\wamp\www\codes\laravel5\portpapa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
> line 835: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ 
> $methods ]] in class Illuminate\Routing\Route (View: ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Laravel already have this by default. If you create a view called  `errors/404.blade.php` in the `resources/views` folder, this will be automatic.

If you want to handle the 404 error with custom code, just catch the `NotFoundHttpException` exception in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        // handle here
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $methods ]] in class Illuminate\Routing\Route . I guess I might have used Route in some place I should not.

Answer (score 3):

If the route is not defined, the NotFoundHttpException will be throw.
The exceptions are managed in Larevel in app/Exceptions/handler.php.

You have to check if the exception is `NotFoundHttpException` and, in this case, return the correct view.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e))
    {       
        if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
            return response()->view('my.view', [], 404);
        }
        return $this->renderHttpException($e);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-handle-laravel-5-exceptions).